# Do task if custom variable is set to true

Tags: yaml, ansible

I would like to do a task if and only if a custom variable (from the, main, playbook.yml) is set to true. I've had a couple of attempts at it, but none worked.

Here's my latest attempt:

In `tasks/main.yml`:

```
- name: Unpack Nexus main configurations
  unarchive:
    src="{{ nexus_configs_download_dir }}/{{ nexus_main_configurations }}"
    dest="{{ nexus_installation_dir }}"
    creates="{{ nexus_installation_dir }}/nexus-professional-{{ nexus_version }}"
    force=no
    copy=false
    owner={{ nexus_os_user }}
    group={{ nexus_os_group }}
    mode="0755"
  when: "{{ nexus_main_select_configuration | True }}"
  tags: 
    - unpack
    - ansible-nexus

- name: Unpack Nexus sync configurations
  unarchive:
    src="{{ nexus_configs_download_dir }}/{{ nexus_sync_configurations }}"
    dest="{{ nexus_installation_dir }}"
    creates="{{ nexus_installation_dir }}/nexus-professional-{{ nexus_version }}"
    force=no
    copy=false
    owner={{ nexus_os_user }}
    group={{ nexus_os_group }}
    mode="0755"
  when: "{{ nexus_sync_select_configuration | True }}"
  tags: 
    - unpack
    - ansible-nexus

- name: Unpack Nexus proxy configurations
  unarchive:
    src="{{ nexus_configs_download_dir }}/{{ nexus_proxy_configurations }}"
    dest="{{ nexus_installation_dir }}"
    creates="{{ nexus_installation_dir }}/nexus-professional-{{ nexus_version }}"
    force=no
    copy=false
    owner={{ nexus_os_user }}
    group={{ nexus_os_group }}
    mode="0755"
  when: "{{ nexus_proxy_select_configuration | True }}"
  tags: 
    - unpack
    - ansible-nexus
```

In `defaults/main.yml`:

```
---
# [REDACTED]
nexus_installation_dir: '/usr/share'
nexus_main: false
nexus_sync: false
nexus_proxy: false
nexus_main_select_configuration: "{{ nexus_main | bool }}"
nexus_sync_select_configuration: "{{ nexus_sync | bool }}"
nexus_proxy_select_configuration: "{{ nexus_proxy | bool }}"
```

In the main `playbook.yml`:

```
---

- hosts: 127.0.0.1
  connection: local
  roles:
  - { role: covs.nexus,
      nexus_version: '2.14.1-01',
      nexus_installation_dir: '/opt',
      nexus_port: 8080,
      nexus_webapp_context_path: '/',
      nexus_proxy: true,
      become: yes}
```

I get the following error with this latest attempt:

```
TASK [covs.nexus : Unpack Nexus main configurations] ***************************
fatal: [127.0.0.1]: FAILED! => {"failed": true, "msg": "The conditional check '{{ nexus_main_select_configuration | True }}' failed. The error was: template error while templating string: no filter named 'True'. String: {{ nexus_main_select_configuration | True }}\n\nThe error appears to have been in '/home/ubuntu/covs-nexus-ansible/tasks/main.yml': line 276, column 3, but may\nbe elsewhere in the file depending on the exact syntax problem.\n\nThe offending line appears to be:\n\n\n- name: Unpack Nexus main configurations\n  ^ here\n"}
```

I was trying to get help from [this page](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/playbooks_conditionals.html) but their examples are based on running a command on the machine then based on that command do something. I could not find an example of conditionals based on a variable from another yml file in the playbook.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay since I was still having issues with the way I was doing it (check the comments from [Konstantin's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40979125/4557537)), I've ended up changing the way I was doing it with another, not the prettiest, solution.. This is what I've done (and I'm sure there's a better way to do this):

I've removed anything related to this problem in the `defaults/main.yml`, and moved the tasks related to this to the the actual playbook yaml file.

Which means now I have 3 main playbook yaml files to choose from.

Here's one of them (the other ones are similar):

`nexus-sync.yml`:

```
---

- hosts: 127.0.0.1
  connection: local
  roles:
  - { role: covs.nexus,
      nexus_version: '2.14.1-01',
      nexus_installation_dir: '/opt',
      nexus_port: 8080,
      nexus_webapp_context_path: '/',
      become: yes}
  tasks:
    - name: Remove all contents of configuration dir
      become: yes
      shell: rm -rf {{ nexus_working_dir }}/conf
      tags:
        - ansible-nexus
    - name: Unpack Nexus sync configurations
      become: yes
      unarchive:
        src="{{ nexus_sync_configurations }}"
        dest="{{ nexus_working_dir }}"
        creates="{{ nexus_working_dir }}/conf"
        force=no
        copy=false
        owner={{ nexus_os_user }}
        group={{ nexus_os_group }}
        mode="0755"
        recursive: true
      notify:
        - 'restart nexus'
      tags: 
        - unpack
        - ansible-nexus
```

If someone posts another working answer that's better than this, I'll choose that as the solved answer, as this one works but not the best solution out there.

Answer (score 2):

The very first example there uses variable `ansible_os_family`:

```
  - name: "shut down Debian flavored systems"
    command: /sbin/shutdown -t now
    when: ansible_os_family == "Debian"
```

Pay attention to this quote:

> This is easy to do in Ansible with the when clause, which contains a raw Jinja2 expression **without double curly braces**.

So you just need to remove them (and also those strange `| True` filters).

```
when: nexus_sync_select_configuration
```

Comment: So doing `when: nexus_sync_select_configuration` means when it's true? Wouldn't I have to do `when: nexus_sync_select_configuration == True` ?

Comment: Hmm, so in both ways (your answer and my comment).. It's now skipping those steps everytime..

Comment: `nexus_sync: false`, so is `nexus_sync_select_configuration: "{{ nexus_sync | bool }}"`, so your when-condition is always negative, though task skips all the time.

Comment: Okay, so doesn't nexus_sync: true (from playbook.yml) overwrite it? Just like how it overwrites: `nexus_installation_dir`.. What do I need to do in this case?

Comment: I've removed those false statements and put them in the main playbook yaml but that still doesn't work (still skips). So in the main playbook yaml file I have the following: `nexus_main: false`, `nexus_sync: true` and `nexus_proxy: false`